# OpenVPN: How to change the routing in the .ovpn file?

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I got a `.ovpn` file from our "network guy".
I tried to import it to NetworkManager, but that didn't work:

```
 $ sudo nmcli connection import type openvpn file ~/.ssh/foo.ovpn
```

The connection appeared in the UI, but can't connect.

So I tried connecting on a command line:

```
sudo openvpn --config ~ondra/.ssh/arpage/ozizka@kufw1-1.arpage.ch.ovpn
```

This works. Although, all traffic goes through that VPN. The only thing that resembles the option "Only use this connection for it's traffic" in NetworkManager's UI is `route remote_host`, but `openvpn` complains about it, so I had to comment it out.

- How can I change the routing in the `.ovpn` file?
- Where is the reference manual for the `.ovpn` file?

---

Here's a part of that file:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote *** 20443
verify-x509-name "..."
#route remote_host 255.255.255.255 net_gateway
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
auth-user-pass
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
comp-lzo no
route-delay 4
verb 3
reneg-sec 0
<ca>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if `remote_host` has some special meaning or is an alias for `0.0.0.0`.
The issue at my side was that there was pseudo-default route pushed from the OpenVPN server: `0.0.0.0/1` routed to `vpn_gateway`, and that was somehow killing the traffic.

So originally I did

```
sudo route del -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 128.0.0.0
# Or - equivalently:
sudo ip route del 0.0.0.0/1
```

And later, the "network guy" removed it from the commands pushed by the OpenVPN server.